# How to solve a Shapes.PasteSpecial:Invalid request when pasting Bitmap?

Tags: excel, vba, bitmap, powerpoint

I am trying to create a VBA routine to copy some tables from excel and paste them in my PowerPoint presentation as bitmap. 
I have tried different ways, but I keep getting this error: Shapes.PasteSpecial:Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable. 
I am not sure how to solve it, as for some slides the code seems to work and for other slides it doesn't.
The code is currently as follows:

```
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
DestinationPPT = ("C:xxxxx.pptx")
PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open (DestinationPPT)
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
Set ArquivoAberto = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySlide = Nothing
Set myShape = Nothing

Final = 142
j = 5

For i = 9 To Final

Set mySlide = Nothing
Set myShape = Nothing
ArquivoAberto.Sheets("B. Metrics On").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + 6, 8)).Select
Selection.Copy

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(j)
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=1

Selection.Clear

Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        myShape.Name = "CashOn"
j = j + 1
i = i + 6

Next

Set ArquivoAberto = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduced your error.
On my computer it work well:/
I think that the clipboard is empty when this happened.
Try code with DoEvents after Copy.
Maybe this will work:

```
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
DestinationPPT = ("C:xxxxx.pptx")
PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open (DestinationPPT)
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
Set ArquivoAberto = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySlide = Nothing
Set myShape = Nothing

Final = 142
j = 5

For i = 9 To Final

Set mySlide = Nothing
Set myShape = Nothing
ArquivoAberto.Sheets("B. Metrics On").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + 6, 8)).Select
Selection.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
DoEvents

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(j)
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=1
DoEvents
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.Clear

Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        myShape.Name = "CashOn"
j = j + 1
i = i + 6

Next

Set ArquivoAberto = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have add an Application.wait  before the SpecialPaste and it seems it is working now. I will improve it with your suggestion